# Why does my main file not recognize my other file

Tags: c++

I have a file called MyVector.cpp:

```
#include "MyVector.h"


MyVector::MyVector(double x ,double y ,double z){
    this->v[0] = x;
    this->v[1] = y;
    this->v[2] = z;
    this->v[3] = 1.0;

}
```

and header with the name MyVector.h:

```
#ifndef MYVECTOR_H
#define MYVECTOR_H

#include <iostream>


class MyVector{
    public:
        double v[4];

        MyVector(double x ,double y ,double z);

};

#endif
```

In the main file I try to use the class MyVector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyVector.h"


int main(){
    MyVector v(1.0 ,2.0 ,3.0);

    std::cout << v.v[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << v.v[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << v.v[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << v.v[3] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But all I get is an error saying the refrence to the constructor (MyVector) is undefined.
`undefined reference to` MyVector::MyVector(double, double, double)`

I tried to change the names of the class but it didnt work

Comment: How do you compile and link your code?

Comment: @MSpiller I use vscode with extentions and my compiler is mingw

Comment: @MRubiksCube Have you done anything to configure VS Code to compile and link `MyVector.cpp` with `main.cpp`? I think VS Code shows the compiler command used in the build readout. Make sure that it includes both sources files, and not just `main.cpp`.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding the header files like `MyVector.h` though some C++ magic allow other files to find the corresponding source file `MyVector.cpp`. This is not true. All sources files that are part of the program must be passed to the compiler and linker by you (or by your IDE). In your case this is not happening because you have not configured VSCode correctly.

Comment: The instructions you should have followed are [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson). It's an easy detail to miss, we get your question quite frequently.

Comment: Remember that VSCode by default builds only the active file into your executable. The official documentation tells you that and how to change your `tasks.json` to have it build all files in your folder: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: VSCode is not a beginner-friendly IDE. I recommend uninstalling it and installing one that just works out of the box, without you having to fiddle with extensions and json files. Or just go with a simple text editor and a command line, you will learn more and faster this way.

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compile by yourself using `g++` ?

Something like this should work :

```
g++ -o vector main.cpp MyVector.cpp
```

Comment: It's good advice but it's not really an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @john I interpreted his problem as he couldn't compile his code because of its different classes, so I advised him to compile it directly from the compiler that's why ! At least the question needs to be clarified to highlight the real "problem".

Comment: Is `MyVector.h` in there intentionally? You don't need to separately compile header files.

Comment: No it's not, I'm editing it, it was more likely to clarify, I prefer to add them personally